# SQL Server Update with complex logic

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table which I need to update to value of Y, but this update is based upon some results from other tables, and I am not sure how to do this.

Basically, I need to complete the following checks

1. I need to check from the table I need to update that the other table has exactly 19 matching rows
2. In those matching rows that one of the fields is not null
3. I have two other tables which I need to check that records exist in the latter table plus to ensure that the matching records in the latter do not contain the value of "Y" in one of the fields.

My approach to this is to use UNIONs, but I would like someone to advise me whether this approach is correct or whether there is a much better way of doing it:

```
SELECT '1'
FROM t_A_Outbound
Where NOT HEADER IN (Select HEADER FROM t_B_Outbound)

UNION

SELECT '1'
FROM t_A_Outbound
Where HEADER IN (Select HEADER FROM t_B_Outbound
                 WHERE NOT INCOMPLETE ='Y')

UNION

Select '1'
From t_C_Outbound
Where ValueString = ''

UNION

Select '1'
From t_C_Outbound
WHERE Exists(Select Count(key), HEADER
             From t_C_Outbound IN (SELECT HEADER FROM table_that_needs_updating)
             Group By HEADER
             Having NOT Count(Cast(key as Int)) = 19)
```

I thought of using 1 as flag to say if this value comes back to update the field in the table I need to change.

Can anyone advise me?

Comment: Could you show us your desired `update` statement?  I'm thinking that you can do everything you need to validate the data using the `from` and `where` clauses.

Comment: I haven't written the actual update statement, but I am looking to see whether the approach I am doing is correct. So, it is advice I am looking for

Comment: You're making quite a collection of strings containing the digit `1`.  I'm not sure how that helps.  Since you can't communicate what you would update if all of your validation was successful, I can't do much more except to suggest either using `if` or `update` from a `join`.

Comment: user92546 On the outside of the query, what I was thinking is update table_that_needs_updating Set Complete = 'N' where 'QUERY BIT GOES IN HERE'. What I am trying to find out if there is another of achieving this update to the table

Comment: Unfortunately no, because some haven't even been responded to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is rather unclear to me what unions do for you.

You want an update statement something like:

```
update table
    set y = . . .
    where header in (Select header
                     From t_C_Outbound
                     Group By HEADER 
                     Having Count(*)= 19 and
                            count(KEY) = count(*)
                    ) and
          header in (select header
                     from other table
                     group by header
                     having sum(case when col = 'Y' then 1 else 0 end) = 0
                    )
```

and so on.  You don't describe the problem clearly enough to give more detailed code.